# Donde está la pestaña "interesantes"

Tags: soporte

En la versión inglesa de Stackoverflow hay una pestaña [`interesantes`](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=interesting) con todas las preguntas actuales con las etiquetas seleccionadas. Sin embargo no puedo encontrarla en la versión española del sitio. ¿es cierto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que he visto de los sitios de la red de Stack Overflow, el único sitio que tiene la pestaña *interesting* es la página original en inglés.  El resto de sitios tiene en su lugar la pestaña *active*.

Comment: Sí, pero no son iguales. Los "interesantes" me parecen más útiles.

Comment: Y estoy de acuerdo contigo pero lo que yo supongo es que en los sitios de menor tráfico como este, la página de preguntas "interesantes" no cambiaría mucho.

Comment: Tengo entendido que la pestaña "Interesting" de http://stackoverflow.com/?tab=interesting utiliza las etiquetas que el usuario ha marcado como favoritas, lo que hace esta pestaña súmamente útil.